# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Sound Design's [second moderator election](https://sound.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidate who nominated:

[image: <MOD1_NAME>]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

(P.S. - Apologies for being one day late to post this. Turns out, I gotta do this bit by hand!)